# thymeleaf + springboot + springsecurity project configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

- spring security 4.2.2
- thymeleaf 3.0.3

i had a spring boot project which later started to use spring security to protect some API endpoints, the authentication went well using the **default** login page that spring security implements, but now i have to implement a **custom** login page.

i am trying to follow this tutorial: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html

but i find myself unable to correctly display the custom form.

i am mostly sure that is because i have not defined any **template resolver**, but in all fairness even with all the examples i have read i still cant quite figure out how to. 
so here that i am using:

in **SecurityConfig**

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/survey/report/**").hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE)
    .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .and().logout();
  }
}
```

custom and newly created **login controller**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(){return "login";}
}
```

the **login.htm** as the guide:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:include="layout :: head(title=~{::title},links=~{})">
<title>Please Login</title>
</head>
<body th:include="layout :: body" th:with="content=~{::content}">
<div th:fragment="content">
<form name="f" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please Login</legend>
        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-error">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

as things stands now i believe i should implement a new class that confirures my thymeleaf (making asumtions here) but i already have a class that configures my application: **MvcConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements ServletContextInitializer,
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
```

i though that i could add there the template resolver but to no avail. since my template is not recognized
[image: template not accesible]

*note: not adding the template resolver to the **MvcConfiguration** has the same result as adding it: the template is not accesible*

i know the guide is based on a spring mvc application and i am implementing it in my own project, but if anyone could point me in the right direction i would be very grateful

### edit:

here is the error that i get the most: [java log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fcastillao/paste-stuff/master/thymeleaf%20error.md)

Comment: The exception is saying it can't find "views/login.html" in the ServletContext. In your question, you say your template is named "login.htm". Is that just a typo and you really have named it "login.html"? Where does "login.html" exist in your project? Is it under the WEB-INF/views folder, or somewhere else?

Comment: i have it named login.html its in resources/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your file present under resources/templates
2. Make you have thymeleaf dependency added into your pom.xml (By default thyme leaf resolver resolve the view)